# Creating Pages that show specific blog categories

Tags: categories

How do you:

1) create a page and select "Blog Template" and also choose which category for the Blog's you want.

2) Then create a blog post and choose the category for that page....resulting in a page that shows all the blog posts for that category?

Thanks!

Comment: I was on the same quest to find a plugin that will allow me to post articles based on a specific category or tag wherever i wanted.
The answer i found is Blog-in-Blog plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/blog-in-blog/
Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the functionality of [WordPress 3.0 Menus Subpanel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel). In Dashboard go to 'Appearance' then 'Menus' and you can create a page that will show the posts from a specified category.

Answer (score 3):

WordPress by default creates category  archive that lists all of the category's posts, but if you want to do that in a page then take a look at [List category posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) plugin

> which allows you to list posts from a category into a post/page using the [catlist] shortcode. This shortcode accepts a category name or id, the order in which you want the posts to display, and the number of posts to display. You can use [catlist] as many times as needed with different arguments.